# C# SQL Server connection using server Login

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication, connection

I have a problem with connecting to my SQL server. I keep getting "Login failed for user" error messages, but the user I am trying to login as exists as a login on the server. The connection string I use looks like this:

```
Data Source=[server name];Initial Catalog=[database];User ID=[login name];Password=[login password];
```

Is it because the login exists on the server, but not as a user on the database that I can't use it to login?

If so is it not possible for me to connect to the server using a server login?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct: You need to add the logon as a user to the database.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that there is something else wrong with your connection string.  I know if I have the wrong database or server in the string it will be give me an "unable to login with user..." message.

[image: Error Message Referencing Wrong Database]

Data Source=[server name];Initial Catalog=[database];User ID=[login name];Password=[login password];

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to connect SQL Server (preferrd Language is C#)

```
    Public Sub Start_DB_Connection(servername As String,user As String,password As String,dbname As String)
        Try
            db_con As New SqlConnection
            If Not db_con Is Nothing Then db_con.Close()
            db_con.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; connection timeout=1;", servername, user, password, dbname)

            db_con.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            // show error
        End Try
    End Sub
```